# probability question of n cardinality

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Assume we have an event X which has the cardinality $n$ and $n \ge 2$. What is the probability that we randomly uniformly create 2 DISTINCT permutations of X, such that they are the reverse of each other.

I determined there are $n!$ ways to generate permutations and each permutation has exactly one reverse permutation associated with it. Since we create them uniformly then there are $1/n!$ ways to generate a random permutation. To generate the second one there is a  $1/(n)!-1$ chance to generate a random permutation that is its reverse. Then I multiply them.

So there is $1/n! * 1/(n)!-1 $ chance to generate 2 permutations such that they are the reverse of each other. Is this right??

Comment: You have the right idea, but notation is muddled.  There is a 1/n! probability of  getting a match, assuming first one is anything and second is anything - no restrictions.

Comment: @herbsteinberg it should be 2 distinct permutations so in the second one I subtract one in the denominator. Is my answer/ approach correct?

Comment: You need to clarify the problem statement.  If it is simply a match with no restrictions on choice, then my answer is correct.  What is the exact selection procedure you are trying?

Comment: @herbsteinberg Lets say we generate 2 permutations that must be distinct. What are the chances these permutations are the reverse of each other? That's all the restrictions there are.

Comment: Since the first can be any, the probability is 1.  If there is no restriction on the second it has a probability of 1/n!, or the first is excluded then it has prob. of 1/(n!-1).  Note: use () to avoid ambiguity - 1/n!-1 looks different.